# Android MediaPlayer Error 1, -1002

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am creating an app that plays **mp4 video files**, but when I try to play an specific file I get this error:

```
D/MediaPlayer(12605): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
E/MediaPlayer(12605): error (1, -1002)
E/MediaPlayer(12605): Error (1,-1002)
D/VideoView(12605): Error: 1,-1002
```

I tried to search info about the error [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h), but I didn't find anything very clarifying. Does anyone know what this error means?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I changed my device connection from 3G to Wi-Fi and the video played perfectly... Oh boy. Case closed.

Comment: `-1002` would be `ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST` ([reference](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h?h=jb_2.2_rb2.2))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error codes depends on the player, for StageFright -1002 means "unknown host".

See media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h

```
  enum {
     MEDIA_ERROR_BASE        = -1000,

     ERROR_ALREADY_CONNECTED = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE,
     ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 1,
     ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST      = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 2,
```